# LWC group record by category lightning-tree-grid ignores the hierachy

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I currently have a LWC ( which i didn’t create as totally new to LWC) that returns a lightning-datatable  that allows a user to select many products and then do some logic.

I am now asked to have this structure in Salesforce Where Category is a custom object and product 2 is the standard SF object.
[image: Desired hierarchy]

```
Category 0
    Category 1
        Product2-A
        Product2-B
        Category 1-1
            Product2-C
            Product2-D
        Category 1-2
            Product2-E
    Category 2
        Product2-F
        Category 2-1
                        Product2-G
```

I created the category custom object and attempted to use lightning-tree-grid
Which displays the items but the category hierarchy is ignored.
I reckon i am missing some looping but being too new i can't figure out what i am missing
Output

[image: Current Output]

The JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import LightningTreeGrid from 'lightning/treeGrid';
import getSpotforCats from '@salesforce/apex/ProductsBrowserByCatController.getSpotforCats';
import SystemModstamp from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SystemModstamp';




const columns = [




   {
       label: 'Spot Category',
       fieldName: 'Category_Name__c',
       type: 'text',
       sortable: true,
       initialWidth:400,
       wrapText: true,
       cellAttributes: {
           iconName: 'standard:category',
       },
   },
   {
       label: 'Spot name',
       fieldName: 'prod_name__c',
       type: 'text',
       sortable: true,
       wrapText: true,


   }
];






export default class ProductsBrowserCat extends LightningElement {


   key;
   @track initialized = false;
   @track isloading = false;
   @api recordId;
   @api existingProducts = [];
   @track products;
   columns = columns;
   selectedRows = [];




@track myData = [];


   error;
  
   @wire(getSpotforCats)
   wiredProducts__r({error, data}) {
       if (error) {
           // Handle error
           this.error = error;
       } else if (data) {
           console.log('@@@ data ' +data);
           // Process record data
           var strData = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( data ) );


           strData.map((row, index) => {
               if (row['Products__r']) {
                   row._children = row['Products__r']; //define rows with children
                   delete row.Products__r;
               }    
           });
           this.myData = strData;
       }
   }
```

The HTML:

```
           <lightning-layout-item size='12' padding="arround-small">


               <lightning-tree-grid
                   columns={columns}
                   data={myData}
                   key-field="Category_Name__c"
                   onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
               </lightning-tree-grid>
       
      
       </lightning-layout-item>
```

The controller

```
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<Spot_Category__c> getSpotforCats(){
           return [SELECT id,Category_Name__c, Parent_Category__c, (SELECT name,prod_name__c,ProductCode FROM Products__r) FROM Spot_Category__c];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You returned `Parent_Category__c`, but you're not actually building a hierarchy with that data. First, create a object mapped by the category Id, then add each category to the parent category's `_children` property. Also, you're using `map` incorrectly, it should be `forEach` as used here, or better, you can just use map as intended.

```
// Transform Products__r to _children, copy data
let mappedData = data.map((v) => {
  return {
    ...v,
    _children: v.Products__r?.map((product) => ({ ...product })) || [],
  };
});
// Map into an object by Id
let categoryById = mappedData.reduce(
  (p, v) => {
    p[v.Id] = v;
    return p;
  },
  { null: { _children: [] } }
);
// Add children to parent
Object.entries(categoryById).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  k !== 'null' && categoryById[v.Parent_Category__c || null]._children.push(v);
});
// List of root categories
this.myData = categoryById[null]._children;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sfdcfox for helping me. I am missing a lot of things indeed. I am trying to understand all you 've said and how to code this too so i can reuse and adapt  on my own for next time. I have also pasted this directly though getting  [LWC component's wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[item is not defined]] ==> How do you declare 'item '?

Comment: @Langloic `item` was an AI-generated typo (code pilot, not chatGPT), lol. I had refactored the variables, but missed that one. I've edited this answer to be correct.

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox, it makes more sense now.  'p' in 'p[k.Parent_Category__c]._children.push(v);' didn't seem to be declared so i did before 'let categoryById' but now i get : Original error:
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_children')]].  any hint of what could be wrong?

Comment: @Langloic I made some assumptions about the data; it may be that the values are `undefined` rather than `null`. You might need to change each instance of null to undefined. If you can share some actual example data (as seen by the client using `console.log(data)`, I'd be happy to readjust the code to match.

Comment: @sfdxfox is this ok ? {"Id":"a1S7E0000039VeRUAU","Category_Name__c":"Category 0"},{"Id":"a1S7E00000395keUAA","Category_Name__c":"Category 1","Products__r":[{"Spot_Category__c":"a1S7E00000395keUAA","Id":"01t6700000CwxjnAAB","Name":"Product2 - A","prod_name__c":"Product2 - A"}]},{"Id":"a1S7E00000395nYUAQ","Category_Name__c":"Category 1 - 1","Parent_Category__c":"a1S7E00000395keUAA","Products__r":[{"Spot_Category__c":"a1S7E00000395nYUAQ","Id":"01t6700000Cwxl5AAB","Name":"Product2 - B","prod_name__c":"Product2 - B"},

Comment: @Langloic Thanks. It was just a couple of careless mistakes on my part. I made some small revisions, it looks like it should be fine now.

Comment: @sfdxfox , Thank you so much much.